# XmlSerializer error Serializing Interface Objects

Tags: c#, interface, xml-serialization

I have a list of objects that implement a common interface. If I try to simply serialize it I get a nice exception that tells me that the serializer cannot serialize interfaces:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<ICanHasInterface> children = new ObservableCollection<ICanHasInterface>();
public ObservableCollection<ICanHasInterface> Children
{
    get { return children; }
}
```

=> "Cannot serialize member ... of type ... because it is an interface"

Apparently asking the serializer to get the type of the objects and mark the XmlElement with the attribute `xsi:type` (which is done if an object inherits from another class) is too much.
So because I do not want to implement `IXmlSerializable`, I thought up a workaround which looked promising initially:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<ICanHasInterface> children = new ObservableCollection<ICanHasInterface>();
[XmlIgnore()]
public ObservableCollection<ICanHasInterface> Children
{
    get { return children; }
}

[XmlElement("Child")]
public List<object> ChildrenSerialized
{
    get
    {
        return new List<object>(Children);
    }
    set
    {
        Children.Clear();
        foreach (var child in value)
        {
            if (child is ICanHasInterface) AddChild(child as ICanHasInterface);
        }
    }
}
```

With this at least the serialisation works just fine (Note: Either specify `XmlInclude` attributes for the types that can be in the original list or hand over an array of types in the constructor of the serializer), however if the object is deserialized the `Children` collection ends up empty because the `set` block is never reached during deserialization, I am quite clueless as to why this is; any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On deserialization the serializer uses your property getter to get the collection instance and then calls Add() on it for each item.  It does not call your property setter.  Something like this:

```
YourClass c = new YourClass();
c.ChildrenSerialized.Add(ReadValue());
...
```

In order to keep the collections synchronized you'd need to customize the Add() behavior of the collection you return from the property getter.

A better option is to change the ChildrenSerialized property to use an object[].  For arrays, the serializer reads the value into an array and then calls your property setter with the value.